# Azure Pipelines: Looping over variable groups and passing values to template

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to loop over variable groups defined in Pipelines -> Library -> Variable groups and pass their variables to a template. I have it working without a loop, but once the loop is added the build fails.

```
# sandbox.yaml
parameters:
    - name: myList
      displayName: "My List"
      type: object
      default:
        - CustomerName: Customer1
          VariableGroupName: 'CustomerGroupName1'
          # p1: ""
          # p2: ""
          # p3: ""
        - CustomerName: Customer2
          VariableGroupName: 'CustomerGroupName2'
          # p1: ""
          # p2: ""
          # p3: ""

stages:
  - stage: "IterateOverServices"
  - ${{ each item in parameters.myList }}: 
    - stage: '${{ item.CustomerName }}'
      variables:
      - group: '${{ item.VariableGroupName }}'

      - template: '/templates/ServiceVariablesTemplate.yaml'
        parameters:
          customerName: '${{item.CustomerName}}'
          p1: '$(p1)'
          p2: '$(p2)'
          p3: '$(p3)'
```

```
# ServiceVariablesTemplate.yaml
parameters:
  - name: customerName
    default: ""
  - name: p1
    default: ""
  - name: p2
    default: ""
  - name: p3
    default: ""

jobs:
  - job: "VariableGroupExpansionJob"
    pool:
      name: "PoolName"
      
    steps:
      - download: none

      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Values For ${{parameters.customerName}}'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |

              Write-Host "Customer Name = ${{parameters.customerName}}"
              Write-Host "p1 = ${{parameters.p1}}"
              Write-Host "p2 = ${{parameters.p2}}"
              Write-Host "p3 = ${{parameters.p3}}"
```

Is there any way to modify this to prevent writing out each stage for each variable group?

Edit: working version

```
# sandbox.yaml
parameters:
    - name: myList
      displayName: "My List"
      type: object
      default:
        - CustomerName: Customer1
          VariableGroupName: 'CustomerGroupName1'
          p1: ""
          p2: ""
          p3: ""
        - CustomerName: Customer2
          VariableGroupName: 'CustomerGroupName2'
          p1: ""
          p2: ""
          p3: ""

        
stages:

    - stage: 'DeployCustomer1'
      variables:
      - group: 'Customer1Service'

      jobs:
      - template: '/templates/ServiceVariablesTemplate.yaml'
        parameters:
          clientName: 'Customer1'
          p1: '$(p1)'
          p2: '$(p2)'
          p3: '$(p3)'

    - stage: 'DeployCustomer2'
      variables:
      - group: 'Customer2Service'

      jobs:
      - template: '/templates/ServiceVariablesTemplate.yaml'
        parameters:
          clientName: 'Customer2'
          p1: '$(p1)'
          p2: '$(p2)'
          p3: '$(p3)'
```

Comment: What is the error? Also, I guess that `ServiceVariablesTemplate.yaml` file is not relevant, right?

Comment: Please provide working example (without a loop)

Comment: Error: /templates/ServiceVariablesTemplate.yaml (Line: 13, Col: 1): Unexpected value

Comment: editing post to include working version